# can write file with zlib but cannot read it back

Tags: c++, stream, zlib

i want to be able to store data into a `data.bin.gz using` using `zstr` (a library that use `zlib`). I succeed to write into the file, but i cannot read it back. Here is a short example.

```
std::auto_ptr<std::ostream> ofs = std::auto_ptr<std::ostream>(new zstr::ofstream(fileName));

std::string str("hello world");
ofs.get()->write(str.c_str(), 11);
std::cout << "data sent: " << str << std::endl;

std::auto_ptr<std::istream> ifs = std::auto_ptr<std::istream>(new zstr::ifstream(fileName));

std::streamsize buffSize = 11;
char* buff = new char [11];
// fill buff to see if its content change
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    buff[i] = 'A';
}

ifs.get()->read(buff, buffSize);
std::cout << std::string(buff, buff+11) << std::endl;

delete [] buff;
```

i fill buff with some specfic content to see if it changes when reading the stream. but it does not change.

Comment: (1) you're opening the file for reading before you've written anything to it. Instead, open the file for writing, put data in it, and close it. Then open the file for reading and read it. (2) the `auto_ptr`s are deprecated and unnecessary (`fstream` objects are already automatic resource managers and will close the file when they go out of scope).

Comment: sorry your rigth. i did not paste the line at the right place. i edited the post as i do it in my project as it is now. thanks for the point regard auto_ptr.

Comment: You still have not closed the file. You need to either call `ofs->close()` or put `{}` around the first five lines in order to make it automatically close when `ofs` is destroyed at the end of scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version that does approximately what you're asking for, but using standard file streams, not the non-standard zstr library which doesn't seem essential here:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std::string_literals;

int main()
{
    constexpr auto fileName = "test.bin";

    {
        const auto str = "hello world"s;
        auto       ofs = std::ofstream( fileName, std::ios::binary );
        ofs.write( str.data(), str.size() );
    } // ofs is closed here by RAII

    auto buff = std::vector<char>(100, 'A');
    auto ifs  = std::ifstream( fileName, std::ios::binary );
    ifs.read(buff.data(), buff.size());
    std::cout << std::string(buff.data(), buff.data()+11) << '\n';
}
```

It outputs `hello world` as expected. See it live on <kbd>[Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a237f608acebfd9)</kbd>.

Notes:

1. I removed the `auto_ptr` and added the proper scoping.
2. I do not manage memory manually (`new`/`delete`), which is bad form. Instead I use `std::vector` and `std::string`.
3. I added the `std::ios::binary` flag to the `fstream` constructors to open in binary mode, since that is what it seems you ultimately want to do. This may not be needed with the zstr library you're using.
4. I made the buffer larger, as if I don't know what's in the file. Then I read from it as much space as I've allocated. When printing the result, I use the "insider knowledge" that there are 11 valid bytes. An alternative would be to initialize the vector to all zeros (the default) and just print it as a string:

```cpp
    auto buff = std::vector<char>( 100 );
    auto ifs  = std::ifstream( fileName, std::ios::binary );
    ifs.read(buff.data(), buff.size() - 1); // Keep one zero for null terminator
    std::cout << buff.data() << '\n';
```

which you can also see live on <kbd>[Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/477279cf6aa0bb3a)</kbd>.

I also modernized in a few other ways just for fun and educational purposes:

1. I use `constexpr` on a constant known at compile-time.
2. I use the string literal suffix `s` on `str` to create a `std::string` with greater concision.
3. I use '[almost always auto](https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/)' style for declaring objects.
4. Use `\n` instead of `std::endl` because [you don't need the extra flush](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GMqQOEZYVJQ) (good habit to be in).